# IBOutlet property with __kindof?

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

Can we declare an IBOutlet property with `__kindof` annotations?

```
@property (nonatomic, nullable, weak) __kindof IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

I had a property defined like this. But cannot drag a line in interface builder as there are no tableView outlet showed. If I remove the __kindof before IBOutlet, it works as expect.

Tried in Xcode 7.1.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with this declaration? If you describe what you're trying to do, we might be able to give better advice.

Comment: It's not clear what __kindof is supposed to add here. You are explicitly declaring a class as UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
@property IBOutlet something
#else
@property __kindof something
#endif
```